# Hibernate With H2 Database: SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

My unit tests are completely working with Postgres, but when i switch to H2 i got the following exception:

*SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [inspection]*

Here is my application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  server:
    port: 8080

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: test
    password: test

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      #defaultSchema: public
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      hbm2ddlAuto: validate
      showSql: true
      jdbcBatchSize: 20

  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: /db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    user: test
    password: test

  # http://localhost:8080/h2-console
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

The liquibase changesets are executed according to the logger, and if i switch back to Postgres the unit tests are working well with the same changesets.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your SQL statements are correct for PostgreSQL, it doesn't mean that they will work with a different database.

It's possible that for H2, some slightly different queries are needed to work with Hibernate ORM.
You should check how Hibernate ORM generates the schema for H2 and compare it to the one you have for PostgreSQL.

I suspect that in this case the problem is related to table names being case sensitives in H2.